# how do you set the admin password on openldap 2.4

Tags: linux, openldap

I am getting started with openLdap 2.4 and am having a bit of trouble, all the examples I see seem to refer to previous versions which used the text config file slapd.conf but from what I see on discussions about v2.4, this has been deprecated.

I thought prehaps I needed to add a user, and log in as them>  but when I try and run an ldapadd command, I get a prompt to enter a password:

```
Enter LDAP Password: 
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

Notes:  I installed openldap server via yum (in fedora 15), and have installed phpldapadminbut also can try things on the command line if anyone has suggestions.

After installing and starting I get the following response from a search:

```
# ldapsearch -x -b '' -s base '(objectclass=*)' namingContexts
# extended LDIF
# LDAPv3
# base <> with scope baseObject
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: namingContexts 
dn:
namingContexts: dc=my-domain,dc=com    
# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

I am glad to remove and reinstall the server if that helps, can anyone provide a link to tips that works for version 2.4 for a new setup?

Comment: Off-topic; belongs on [sf]

Comment: thanks.  didn't actually know that sister site existed.    Cheers.  http://serverfault.com/questions/438777/how-do-you-set-the-admin-password-on-openldap-2-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

slapd.conf still works in OpenLDAP 2.4, however 'de-emphasised' it may be in the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

This is old, but the question and non-answer pop up on searches a lot.  First, run slappasswd to generate a password.

```
slappasswd 
New password: ************
Re-enter new password: *************
{SSHA}OM5mbC3/kQPAg8MH6FOqXkATjLjt2IZ2
```

Then use that value to populate your backend's config.

```
ldapmodify -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// << E0F
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}qUoTRPwppaedqHQTgYOPYWokr3SiXjbK
E0F
```

Your dn may be different than the dn shown here. The config databases are found, on RHEL7, in /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config.  Now you can log in using the default rootdn.

If you wish, you can set your own value for the root dn:

```
ldapmodify -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// << E0F
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com
E0F
```

Comment: Is there no cleaner way to do this?

Comment: What if I get this:
`ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)`

Answer (score 2):

## [2022] OpenLDAP 2.4.49

CVVS's answer from 2014 is *almost* still applicable. There are only 2 changes necessary to make it work again:

1. The index of the database is now `olcDatabase={1}mdb` instead of `{2}hdb`. (`cn=config` is kept).
2. You must use the modification type `replace` instead of `add`.

Putting it together:

```bash
ldapmodify -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// << E0F
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}qUoTRPwppaedqHQTgYOPYWokr3SiXjbK
E0F
```

Answer (score 1):

Here my working solution:

```sh
ldapsearch -LLL -Y EXTERNAL -H  ldapi:/// -b cn=config olcRootDN=cn=admin,dc=my,dc=company,dc=com dn olcRootDN olcRootPW
```

Now create new password by:

```sh
NEW_PWD={{TYPE_NEW_PASSWORD_HERE}}

PWD_HASH=$(slappasswd -s ${NEW_PWD})
echo "Your password hash is \"${PWD_HASH}\"."
```

Paste the following code:

```sh
ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// << E0F
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
replace: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: ${PWD_HASH}
E0F
```

You will get:

```sh
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=my,dc=company,dc=com
olcRootPW: {SSHA}k1S8N/A4eb7Ds8oBgAhb9TmPfVT9vl2U
```

To fix the two passwords access (the old and new one), paste:

```sh
OLD_PWD=admin

ldappasswd -h localhost -p 389 -x -D "cn=admin,dc=my,dc=company,dc=com" -w "${OLD_PWD}" -a "${OLD_PWD}" -s "${NEW_PWD}"
```